# OpenCL quasi-quoting

Tags: haskell, opencl

I'm looking for a way to use OpenCL nicely in Haskell, and found [these slides](http://amddevcentral.com/afds/assets/presentations/2910_3_final.pdf) ([alternative source](http://benedictgaster.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/2910_3_final.pdf)) by Benedict Gaster. They mention an impressive “HOpenCL Contextual API” but I can't find anything tangible.

The only thing coming close to the C quasiquotation shown seems to be [language-c-quote](https://github.com/mainland/language-c-quote/blob/master/Language/C/Quote/OpenCL.hs) and its OpenCL-C support ends with the types, it doesn't support the extra keywords.

And [accelerate](https://github.com/AccelerateHS) is something completely different, and mainly for CUDA, with the OpenCL backend in early alpha.

Then there's [HIPERFIT](https://github.com/HIPERFIT) where no code was posted for a year (but the project is still running), which seems to combine the C quasiquotation and OpenCL, their bindings are even called HOpenCL, but are just a wrapper, nothing to see of the monadic transforms etc.

None of this seems close to finished and ready to build upon…

Any news or other projects I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for exactly the same thing, and I came across this: https://github.com/bgaster/hopencl

This must be what Benedict Gaster - who is not working for AMD anymore - was talking about. There is not a tremendous amount of activity on the git, but there was an update about 2 months ago, which is still better than a year.

EDIT: Actually J. Garret Morris (the other author of HOpenCL) created a fork: https://github.com/jgbm/hopencl

Comment: I think I came across this, must have missed the [example using quasiquotation](https://github.com/bgaster/hopencl/blob/master/examples/Tutorial1.hs), I only saw those loading external files

Answer (score 2):

First seeing you post here now. I'm the author of the HIPERFIT-hopencl package and sort of also a bit responsible for the language-c-quote OpenCL C support. I apologize for the naming confusion and that we now have two hopencl-packages. I have mailed Benedict Gaster and J. Garret Morris about how we resolve that.

What do you find lacking in language-c-quote? Could you give an example of what OpenCL C code that it doesn't handle?

(PS. I'm new here and could not find a way to comment on your post, so I had to post this as an answer - perhaps I just haven't reached the right "clearing level" yet)